# Emacs open all buffers in read only mode

Tags: read-only-mode

This problem is driving me crazy. Emacs open all buffers including new ones in read only mode (yes, I know that I can do `C-x C-q`). I've tried everything including:

- Delete `.emacs.d/`
- Delete `.config/emacs/init.el`
- Delete `.emacs.el`
- Launch Emacs as: `emacs -q -Q --debug-init (no errors, same behavior)`
- Reinstall Emacs.

I am using gentoo. I've create a new user (guest). Emacs works as expected. I guess the problem is somehow related to my user.

I can open a file in nano, edit it and save it. No problem. Afterwards, I open the same file in emacs it opens in read only mode. I have to hit Ctrl-Q to edit it. I can save it without problems. It's an emacs problem

All the files have write permission, that's why I can open and edit them in nano for instance.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit files in another editor?  This may not be an emacs problem.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Have you checked that you have write permission for the files you are opening?

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I want emacs to open files read-only by default and for me to have to explicitly set it to writeable. Reason being, sometimes I'll be working with say very similar looking configuration files where I want to copy from one to the other but if I'm not careful I end up editing the wrong one by mistake.